# Angular2 one component trigger event and another subscribe and execute some tasks

Tags: angular, events, observable, single-page-application

I am new to angular 2 so please forgive me if my terminology is off.
I have an app that I am writing using angular 2 and I cannot seem to grasp the concept of how events are triggered and handled between components.

The app has a nav sidebar that contains a menu and other logged in user specific data.  When the user is not logged in, the sidebar should be empty and the user logs in, the sidebar should load the appropriate menu and user specific data (the menu changes based on the security level of the user).

I have the data loading as intended but i cant seem to figure out how to tell the sidebar to load the data without forcing a full browser refresh.

The structure of the page is as such:

Header

Left Sidebar

Main Content -> where route components load

Footer

I need the Main Content components to raise an event and the Left Sidebar component to subscribe to that event and perform some work to load the data.

Generally speaking, the data is be loaded after the login service completes and passes control back to the login component that called the service method and will not be touched again until the user logs out.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

create a `LoginData` service and provide it in your bootstrap. The service will have the following fields:

```
loggedIn$: Subject<boolean> = new BehavioralSubject<boolean>(false);
loginData$: Subject<any> = new BehavioralSubject<any>({}); // in case you want to pass specific data

loginSuccessful(data: any): void {
  this.loggedIn$.next(true);
  this.loginData$.next(data);
}
```

then, in your `NavbarComponent`, inject the login service:

```
constructor(private loginSvc: LoginData){}
```

and in your html use the service data, for example:

```
<button type="button" (click)="..." *ngIf="loginSvc.loggedIn$ | async">my profile</button>
```

or if you want to use specific data:

```
 <span *ngIf="loginSvc.loggedIn$ | async">user {{(logindSvc.loginData$ | async).name}}</span>
```

Now in your login handler do:

```
this.http.get('/login', JSON.stringify(loginPayload))
  .map(response => response.json())
  .subscribe(loginData => this.loginSvc.loginSuccessful(loginData));
```